# difference between ga:entranceBounceRate and ga:visitBounceRate

Tags: google-analytics

What is the difference between ga:entranceBounceRate and ga:visitBounceRate ?
I found the following definition from Google analytics like

**ga:visitBounceRate**

- The percentage of single-page visits (i.e., visits in which the
  person left your site from the **first page**).

**ga:entranceBounceRate**

- The percentage of single-page visits (i.e. visits in which the person
  left your site from the **entrance page**).

The Only difference which i see is first page and entrance page. Is both not the same ? How it is different from each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in how the rates are calculated:

> > **ga:entranceBounceRate**
> >
> > The percentage of single-page visits (i.e. visits in which the person left your site from the entrance page).
> >
> > Calculation: **(ga:bounces / ga:entrances) * 100**

**ga:entrances:** The number of entrances to your website measured as the first pageview in a session.

> > **ga:visitBounceRate**
> >
> > The percentage of single-page visits (i.e., visits in which the person left your site from the first page).
> >
> > Calculation: **(ga:bounces / ga:visits) * 100**

**ga:visits:** Counts the total number of sessions.

While they may be nearly identical for the site because entrances often equal visits, if you run it on a page level basis, you could see which pages created a high percentage of bounces and are thus driving up the overall site bounce rate.

In short, [apply ga:entranceBounceRate to a particular page](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253ApageTitle&metrics=ga%253AentranceBounceRate&sort=-ga%253AentranceBounceRate&start-date=2012-09-04&end-date=2012-09-18&max-results=100).

[Apply ga:visitBounceRate to the site](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?metrics=ga%253AvisitBounceRate&start-date=2012-09-04&end-date=2012-09-18).

Comment: When is an entrance not a visit? Any thoughts would be appreciated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681071/when-is-a-google-analytics-entrance-not-a-visit